# Is there a way to extract the strategy of someone shared his mt4 statement?

Tags: foreign-exchange, investment-strategies

I recently found out that Tickmill (a forex broker) hosted competitions on their website. What is great about that is that successful traders shared their account statements and how/when they placed their positions.

Is there a way to extract the strategies that they used?

Comment: Not reliably, no. All you know is the decisions they made; there's no way to determine what lead to those decisions.

Comment: Think of it like this: two people buy a ticket to see the same movie. Did they go for the same reason? Given 10 such choices, you can certainly try to fit a model that reverse-engineers the decision process used to make each choice (see recommender systems as an applied example), but it is going to be imperfect, and there is always multiple models that explain the same last prior behavior but predict different future behavior. But even if you could, the same strategy that worked last year often gets very different results the following year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be utterly foolish to do so. There's no difficulty in figuring out, for any past time period, what would have been the best forex trades to make. How is a list of those going to help you?

Say you suspect that there might be some people with the ability to predict the stock market. You host a competition where people predict stock market results. You get 100,000 entrants.

Of course, most of them are totally wrong. But one of them is very, very right. I mean, spooky right. They're so right, the odds of them being right by chance is, like, 1 in 100,000.

This person is a financial guru whose brain you should pick and whose strategy you should follow, right?

Wrong.

Very wrong.

Obviously wrong.

Following the trades or strategy of forex traders known to have a track record of success is a strategy that is absolutely, unequivocally known to *not work*. The problem is that you would first need some way to distinguish luck from an edge. Do you have any way to do that?